# How to stop image stretch using project.android.imageprocessing library?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, android-imageview, android-image

I am using FastImageProcessing library to apply sketch effect on image.
Using FastImageProcessingView instead of simple image view. I have set height and width to this view is wrap_contain in the xml. Whenever I render image using filter, The FastImageProccessingView is fill the parent layout and image generated using effect is stretch. 
I got bove lib on github,  https://github.com/chrisbatt/AndroidFastImageProcessing.
Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below libraries that fits your requirement

1. Glide - Introduction to Glide, Image Loader Library for Android, recommended by Google
   http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en
   GitHub's : https://github.com/bumptech/glide
2. Android Universal Image Loader (AUIL) -
   GitHub's : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
3. Picasso - http://square.github.io/picasso/
4. Fresco - http://frescolib.org/
   GitHub's : https://github.com/facebook/fresco

Comment: Thanks, but not possible. I am working on image edit tool, have to use above lib.